# UIDatePicker will not show after UITableViewCell select

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

i am using the Code example from Apple, to display a UIDatePicker when a specific UITableViewCell is selected.

how can i change this behavior?

[image: Messed up view]

My Code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

if(indexPath.section == 5) {
    //Date Picker
    UITableViewCell *targetCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    self.pickerView.date = [self.dateFormatter dateFromString:targetCell.textLabel.text];
    if (self.pickerView.superview == nil)
    {
        [self.view.window addSubview: self.pickerView];

        // size up the picker view to our screen and compute the start/end frame origin for our slide up animation
        //
        // compute the start frame
        CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
        CGSize pickerSize = [self.pickerView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
        CGRect startRect = CGRectMake(0.0,
                                      screenRect.origin.y + screenRect.size.height,
                                      pickerSize.width, pickerSize.height);
        self.pickerView.frame = startRect;

        // compute the end frame
        CGRect pickerRect = CGRectMake(0.0,
                                       screenRect.origin.y + screenRect.size.height - pickerSize.height,
                                       pickerSize.width,
                                       pickerSize.height);
        // start the slide up animation
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];

        // we need to perform some post operations after the animation is complete
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

        self.pickerView.frame = pickerRect;

        // shrink the table vertical size to make room for the date picker
        CGRect newFrame = self.tableView.frame;
        newFrame.size.height -= self.pickerView.frame.size.height;
        self.tableView.frame = newFrame;
        [UIView commitAnimations];

    }

}


}
```

Comment: why you use this line 

[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

Comment: Because my other Cells are TextFields and i do not want to have the Cells always highlighted. But this line makes no difference.

Comment: to disable the highlight on cell you have to use this propriety
`[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];`

and make shure that you select the section number 5

Comment: i am debugging with NSLog. i am tapping on the right cell.

Comment: Just to clarify Jussi, what exactly is not working here? Is the date picker simply not showing up on the iPad at all? Did you verify that the relevant block of code is executed in any case?

Comment: UIDatePicker is not shown. if (self.pickerView.superview == nil)
    { this block is executed

Comment: Are you creating pickerview at run time? or you have created at UI interface design time?

Comment: i created it in the Interface Builder and set the outlet

Comment: if you have add it on design time then you need not to add it on window. but you have to change its layout to front.

Comment: it is now displayed, but in a wrong way. check the screenshot

Comment: Now you have to set XY position of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the code you've provided is of your `detail` ViewController, you don't need to set the frame for `pickerRect`. Just need to tell the app that when the orientation changes, the pickerView should rotate with it, as follows

```
self.picker.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
```

You can force the size of picker view by setting its frame, as you've done. Since you are working with a `UISplitViewController`, the pickerView needs to be a subView of your `detail` ViewController, NOT `self.view.window`. Also, go through the sample provided at [this link](http://niftybean.com/main/blog/21-rotating-uipickerview-between-landscape-and-portrait-orientations) to see what other mistakes you were making.

Answer (score 0):

What I see from the given picture, is that you are trying to slide the UIPickerView from the bottom of the screen upwards.

If so, then I think you are not setting frames as you should be.

As shown in [View and Window Architecture](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html), the origin of coordinate system is upper left corner.

I whould do something like this:

```
CGRect pickerFrame = pickerView.frame;
pickerFrame.origin.x = leftTableViewWidth;
pickerFrame.origin.y = screenFrame.size.height + pickerFrame.size.height;
pickerView.frame = pickerFrame;
// begin animation here
pickerFrame.origin.y += pickerFrame.size.height;
// commit animation
```